# Logo not showing on desktop, only on tablet and mobile

Tags: css, wordpress

The header logo is not showing on desktop, but when I decrease the screen's size, I start seeing it (mobile and tablet).

I have tried customizing the site from the customize tool, but there's no option for that.

website is acelebanon.com

Answer (score 1):

Please put the following code in customizer [ Appearance -> Customize -> Additional CSS ] to get the logo in desktop :

```
.pro_logo a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
}
```

Hope it will work.

Comment: Hello, I'm facing the same issue even after updating the code above, could someone help pls. 

1) Website=> https://trinitech.in/
2) Logo => http://trinitech.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/Trinitech_Blue_V1.svg

Thanks in advance. However no logo Issue in mobile & IE, EDGE

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the padding you're giving to `.pro_logo` class

```
.pro_logo { padding: 22px 130px; }
```

Don't use that much padding. With 1-2em (16 - 32px) is enough. Remove the padding and you will see the logo again.

Go this:

```
.pro_logo { padding: 1.5em; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change padding property of your logo wrapper, like this:

```
<style>
.pro_logo { padding: 22px 0; }
</style>
```

It should work on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
.pro_logo {
    padding: 22px 130px;
}
```

remove padding and you can use margin to align logo.